# Changing the Symbol displayed in an MFC AfxMessageBox?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, mfc, desktop-application

Is it possible to display `AfxMessageBox` in my MFC application that does NOT use the default Exclamation sign inside a triangle? And use some other symbol instead (e.g. Question sign inside a circle, etc.) ?

How can this be done? Is there any relatively simple way I can select and specify which symbol to use?

Comment: Did you try to modify the `nType` parameter of `AfxMessageBox` ? It can be any of these [styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/styles-used-by-mfc?view=msvc-170#message-box-styles).

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstring-formatting-and-message-box-display#afxmessagebox), the default is `MB_OK`. It sounds like you aren't using the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

You can fully customize the Icon of the messagebox with [`MessageBoxIndirect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messageboxindirecta) and [`MSGBOXPARAMS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-msgboxparamsa)

Answer (score 1):

`const int iID = AfxMessageBox("Are you having a good day?", MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION);`